# How can I launch node to run a .ts file from IntelliJ?

Tags: node.js, typescript, intellij-idea, webstorm

I have a project set up with IntelliJ IDEA happily compiling `.ts` TypeScript files to `.js` ES6 files. The `.js` files are being dumped neatly next to the `.ts` files.

[image: directory tree]

I'd like to the able to run the .ts files in node.js just like I can with the .js files. E.g. using <kbd>Cmd + Shift + F10</kbd> on `<file>.ts` IntelliJ will launch `node <file>.js` (after running the TypeScript compiler).

After each file edit it feels awkward having to remember to open the .js version before running the file I just edited.

The equivalent experience for a Java programmer would be navigating to the `.class` version of a unit test to execute the edited `.java` file.

Is this just a missing feature in IntelliJ/WebStorm or am I missing something?

Comment: The **rather limited** workaround is to create your Run/Debug Configuration that will do just that -- this way it can be called from ANY file (that's why it's "limited" -- needs to be done manually and only one such config can be active at a time -- but it has sense if you edit the same file/same related files continuously).

Comment: You can use [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) and [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node) to achieve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such feature, as there is no generic way to find the generated file from original one - there are dozens (actually - unlimited) ways to transform them. You can resolve original file from generated one using sourcemaps, but not vice versa. 
Anyway, please vote for [WEB-25389](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25389)

Answer (score 6):

There is now a plugin which adds the ability to run TS files using `ts-node`: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10841-run-configuration-for-typescript

At the moment it does not add the ability to run scratch files.

Comment: Great thing! Remember to add `ts-node` dependency to the project, or install it globally.